# get other fields when retrieving max value from a line in mysql

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have this table:

```
A,B,C
2,5,6
2,8,5
3,4,7
3,4,8
```

I want to group the results by A, and select the max C value. The query for it is something like

```
SELECT A, MAX(C) FROM table GROUP BY A
```

My Question is, how can I retrieve the B value that is next to the max(c) value? Can this be done in the same quesry, or do I need a join query and look for the B field after running the first query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
select A,(select B from Table1 t1 where t1.A=t2.A and T1.C=T2.C) B ,MAX(c) C  
from Table1 T2 group by A;
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d17a3/4)

Comment: Correlated subqueries are very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from table1 t
join 
   (SELECT A, MAX(C) as C 
    FROM table1 GROUP BY A )a
on t.A=a.A
and t.C=a.C
```

Comment: yes this I'm familiar with.. so there is no way with one query, without the need for a double search and a join?

Comment: @n00bprogrammer: I don't think we can get it with single search

Answer (score 1):

This is known as the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html).  To obtain it, you must join the result to your table again:

```
SELECT * FROM table NATURAL JOIN (
  SELECT A, MAX(C) AS C FROM table GROUP BY A
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to your selected columns, but must group by it as well. Otherwise the result is indeterminate.

```
SELECT A, B, MAX(C)
FROM table
GROUP BY A, B
```